# My code is saying that number 1 is prime. How to fix that?

Tags: javascript, primes

So,

I'm starting to learn how to code and now I have only one problem.
My code is functioning very well, until he says that the numbers 1 and 0 are prime.

I already tried to add them to exception, change the calculation and still printing that is prime.

Here's the code:

```js
function testPrimeNumber(num)
{
    Number(num)
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)                
        {
            return ("The number "+num+" isn't prime.");                
        }                                
        else {}                
    }      
    return ("The number "+num+" is prime.");   
} 

console.log("result for 1:", testPrimeNumber(1));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you never enter the loop, so any number below 2 is always returned as prime. you should test for num < 2 explicitly.

Comment: Also `Number(num)` doesn't do anything.

Comment: same for the empty else branch

Comment: Also, `var` is kind of a "retired" variable keyboard, use `let` for values you're going to be reassigning, and `const` for values that should stay the value you give them. Both of those are "block scoped", meaning they get cleaned up when you expect them to be. Anything marked as `var` very much does not. And on a string note, don't use `+`, use template strings: ```return(`The number ${num} isn't prime.`);```. And finally, never compare with `==`, always use `===` unless you can explain why type coercion is necessary.

Comment: This exercise is a test for a selection process, they taught with the variable `var`.

Comment: When I try this way `return('The number ${num} isn't prime.');`, prints everything, like that:
`'The number ${num} isn't prime.'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test for 0 and 1 at the start of the function. At the moment your code is skipping the for loop (because 1 < 2 and 0 < 2) and going straight to saying the number is prime.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer. I'll try my best to solve this, but if I struggle to test 0 and 1 I'll come back here and ask

Comment: Thanks! I just added this test before and everything is running well:
`if (num < 2) {return ("The number "+num+" isn't prime.");}`

Comment: Looks good, good job!